# SSL Connection between IPhone App and Java ServerSocket

Tags: java, cocoa, ssl, ios7, serversocket

I'm trying to establish a SSL Connection between an IPhone App and an Java SSLServerSocket.
My Java Server looks like that:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = null;
    try {
        // set up key manager to do server authentication
        SSLContext ctx;
        KeyManagerFactory kmf;
        KeyStore ks;
        char[] passphrase = "passphrase".toCharArray();

        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        ks.load(new FileInputStream("fsKeystore"), passphrase);
        kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();

        System.out.println("Waiting for Connection");
        SSLServerSocket sslsocketServer = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(9999);
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketServer.accept();
        sslsocket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {

            @Override
            public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Handshake finished");
            }
        });
        InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader;
        bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        String string = "";
        while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            string = bufferedreader.readLine();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            System.out.println(string);
            System.out.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In Objective-c I have implemented this solution:

```
-(id) initWithUrl: (NSString*) host onPort: (NSInteger) port withDelegate:(id<TCPDelegate>) delegate{
self = [super init];
if(self){

    //initTimer
    sendBuffer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSTimer *timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    del=delegate;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)host, port,&readStream,&writeStream);

    iStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    oStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [iStream setDelegate:self];
    [oStream setDelegate:self];

    [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


    [iStream open];
    [oStream open];

    [iStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL
                   forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
    [oStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL
                    forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
     line = @"";
}
return self;
}
```

in the Iphone App I get

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)

Any Idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Crypto is one of the things that you should never do by hand; use the standard libraries instead on both ends.

Comment: Could you please describe that more clearly? What do I use which is not part of the standard libraries?

Comment: What are you running over this SSL socket? These days, it's nearly always HTTP, and I presume that the iOS HTTP client library can handle SSL just as well as `HttpURLConnection` in Java.

Comment: I just send JSON commands over this socket

Comment: Can you make an SSL connection from another client, such as with `openssl s_client`?

Comment: yes, I can make a connection with openssl s_client

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate using NSURLConnection. It has a delegate that you can use for authentication challenges.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW3